# Having 2 Forms with hidden method in Jade with Express

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, express

I want to have an update and delete button, with their respective forms and hidden fields, in the same page.

So the user goes to details and then can either update or delete.

The problem with this if you have 2 hidden fields and post, `methodOverride` gets an array of `['PUT', 'DELETE']` and fails since it is expecting only one in here:

```
method = req.body[key].toLowerCase();
```

How can I have both buttons without Express failing like this? A dirty solution came to mind: having javascript change the attribute of the hidden field, but I want a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `_method` fields are each one in their own form, how do they get both posted at the same time ?
You should have only one `_method` field per form.

Comment: I had nested them. Thanks.